# Add Value to an attribute in XML File using shell script

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I Want to edit XML file thru bash shell script. I am stuck in finding a solution - Kindly share your suggestion if this can be resolved via bash shell script.

I want to add **-Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties** value to jvmParameters attribute In applicationServerInstance tag if it does not exists.

**Input File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
  <applicationServer>
        <applicationServerInstance id="app" serviceName=" App Server" rmiPort="15001" jvmParameters="-Xmx3072m" maxThreads="1000" programParameters="" distributed="false"/>
    </applicationServer>
    <blah>
    </blah>
    <blah abc="123">
    </blah>
</properties>
```

**Ideal Input File(Above file should be be updated as below):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
  <applicationServer>
        <applicationServerInstance id="app" serviceName=" App Server" rmiPort="15001" jvmParameters="-Xmx3072m -Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties" maxThreads="1000" programParameters="" distributed="false"/>
    </applicationServer>
    <blah>
    </blah>
    <blah abc="123">
    </blah>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build on the answer proposed by @Kenazov:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

INPUT=input.xml;
OUTPUT=config.xml

xmllint --format $INPUT |\
sed '/<applicationServerInstance/{/-Dcustom.properties=\/fs0\/share\/custom.properties/!s/\(jvmParameters="[^"]*\)"/\1 -Dcustom.properties=\/fs0\/share\/custom.properties"/}' \
> $OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
sed -i '/<applicationServerInstance/{/-Dcustom\.properties=\/fs0\/share\/custom\.properties/!s/\(jvmParameters="[^"]*\)"/\1 -Dcustom.properties=\/fs0\/share\/custom.properties"/}' file
```

When `<applicationServerInstance` is found, if `-Dcustom.properties=/fs0/share/custom.properties` is not found in the line, it's appended as attribute value to `jvmParameters`.

As @1sloc point out in comment, you'd better sanitize your file using for instance `xmllint` before executing this sed to make sure that `<applicationServerInstance` and `jvmParameters` are on the same line.

The `-i` flag is to edit the file in place.

Comment: To make sure, the file should first be sanitized using `xmllint` or the likes. Only after such a sanitation, we can be sure that `applicationServerInstance` and `jvmParameters` are on the same line, for instance.